# Distribute angles so that consecutive angles are farthest apart

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to find a way to distribute `n` angles from a circle (let's assume at most 360 angles with 1 deg between each, so `0:1:359`).

These angles should be generated as needed so that consecutive angles are as far from each other as possible. Angles cannot be repeated, nor can they be modified to accommodate new angles.

Example:

```
0, 180, 90, 270, 135, 315, 225, 45
```

and so on.

I've tried and can't seem to quite get how to code it. It may be easier to do if I slightly simplify the way I distribute the angles.

I tried to generate according to the last angle while keeping count of how many angles are generated in the current "wave," since the way the circle is going to be divided will be going up (4 times, 8 times, etc.).

```
package uniform_angles;

public class UniformAngles {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int TOTAL_ANGLES = 360;

        // init number of angles to generate
        int numberOfAngles = 12;
        // store positions in array
        int[] positions = new int[numberOfAngles];

        // init first angle (special case for 0)
        int delta = 180;
        positions[0] = 0;
        int firstOrderPassCount = 1;
        //int secondOrderPassCount = 1;

        // generate
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfAngles; i++) {
            if ((firstOrderPassCount*delta) == TOTAL_ANGLES) {
                delta /= 2;
            }

            int nextPos = (positions[i-1] + delta) % TOTAL_ANGLES;

            if ((nextPos % delta) == 0) {
                positions[i] = (positions[i-1] + (2*delta)) % TOTAL_ANGLES;
            }
            firstOrderPassCount++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAngles; i++) {
            System.out.println(positions[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to rebalance the angles after adding new ones?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If you can only add angles, then it's pretty obvious that you'll be dividing the circle in 1,2,4,8,16,.... parts. The next angle to add is pretty straightforward to compute. (Although it will get a bit fiddly when you're no longer dividing exactly by 2.) What have you tried?

Comment: Ideally, generated angles should stay the same, since the goal is to generate more as needed while keeping the existing ones.

Comment: I think I get it now...you add a bunch of points on the circle (thereby defining angles), and later on, you want an algorithm for adding new angles while maximizing the space between all angles.  Is that right?

Comment: @Gene Added what I have written. Seems like I divide the circle by 4 _twice_ (with a 90 deg offset). This is making it harder to grasp.. Which is why I was thinking about "first" and "second order pass" counters. But, you're right, looking at the list I wrote above may help figuring it out!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the algorithm should be used starting from the first angle. If I need only 1 angle, it'll be 0 (or whatever arbitrary parameter is used). If I need two, it'll generate {0,180}, and so on, like the list I included.

Comment: It seems like all you need to do is sort the arcs, and divide the largest found.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque that's a great way to look at it! This should work. I'll post it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add interesting tidbit wrt your problem - it looks like what you want to generate is one-dimensional [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) (aka Quasi-Random MonteCalro).

If you look at Van der Corput/Halton or Sobol sequences in 1D, they look like

```
0 [1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 5/8, 3/8, 7/8, 1/16, ...]
```

basically, dividing [0...1] interval at largest distance at each step.

Van der Corput/Halton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence

Sobol: http://www.deltaquants.com/sobol-sequence-simplified

There is pretty good Java library from Apache for such things: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/random/HaltonSequenceGenerator.html or 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/random/SobolSequenceGenerator.html

PS You need, of course, map QRNG back to your angle interval, [0...2pi] or [0...360]

Comment: Wow that is _exactly_ what I was looking for! I did try to google, but obviously I just didn't know what to look for. It works wonderfully. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague on what "as far from each other as possible" means. It seems likely you mean that the new angle should be midway between a pair of radials with largest interior angle already emitted. If that's true, then you just need simple loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("0 ");
  for (int parts = 1; parts < 90; parts *= 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; ++i)
      printf("%d ", 180 / parts +  360 * i / parts);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This emits

```
0 180 90 270 45 135 225 315 22 67 112 157 202 247 292 337 11 33 56 78 
101 123 146 168 191 213 236 258 281 303 326 348 5 16 27 38 50 61 72 83 
95 106 117 128 140 151 162 173 185 196 207 218 230 241 252 263 275 286 
297 308 320 331 342 353 2 7 13 18 24 30 35 41 47 52 58 63 69 75 80 86 92 
97 103 108 114 120 125 131 137 142 148 153 159 165 170 176 182 187 193 
198 204 210 215 221 227 232 238 243 249 255 260 266 272 277 283 288 294 
300 305 311 317 322 328 333 339 345 350 356
```

If you need more divisions then we can do the angle computation in floating point and round to the nearest integer. The first pair of loops stops when simple rounding would produce a duplicate. This is after emitting 256 angles. To get the last 104, we go through the array and print the indices of the remaining zeros. These must be bracketed by angles that have already been emitted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("0\n");
  int p[360] = {1, 0};
  for (int parts = 1; ; parts *= 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < parts; ++i) {
      int d = 0.5 + 180.0 / parts + 360.0 * i / parts;
      if (p[d]) goto done;
      p[d] = 1;
      printf("%d\n", d);
    }
 done:
  for (int i = 0; i < 360; ++i) if (!p[i]) printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Sorry I did this in C rather than Java. I don't have access to a java environment at the moment.  Should be very easy to port. Note you might as well compute a table of 360 values in advance and store them in a constant array.

Comment: "new angle should be midway between a pair of radials with largest interior angle already emitted." That's not really what I want. So sorry for being vague, though. The new angle from be as "far away" from the previous angle as possible (considering that it circles back, since 360 deg == 0 deg). What you do is you go through the circle linearly (e.g. [22 67 112 157 202 247 292 337]) multiple times while changing the division factor.

Answer (score 0):

As @ReblochonMasque suggested, we can choose the new angle by dividing the longest arc that is farthest from the last generated angle. What we mean by "distance" between two angles is the shortest delta between them (e.g. dist(30,300)=90).

```
public class GenArcs {

    private Vector<Double> positions;

    public GenArcs() {
        positions = new Vector<Double>();
    }

    /**
     * Generate next angle
     * @return next angle
     */
    public double generate() {
        double newAngle = -1.0;

        if (positions.size() > 1) {
            Vector<Double> cpy = new Vector<Double>(positions);

            Collections.sort(cpy);

            // find longest arcs
            Vector<Double> arcs = computeArcLengths(cpy);
            Vector<Integer> longestArcIndexes = getLongestArcIndexes(arcs);

            // compute potential new angles
            Vector<Double> potentialNewAngles = computePotentialAngles(longestArcIndexes, arcs, cpy);

            // choose angle farthest from last angle
            newAngle = getFarthestAngle(potentialNewAngles, positions.get(positions.size()-1));
        } else if (positions.size() == 1) {
            // second angle (since distance between 0.0 and 0.0 is 0.0, so generated angle would still be 0.0; could fix in computeArcLengths(), but eh)
            newAngle = (positions.get(positions.size()-1) + 180) % 360;
        } else {
            // first angle
            newAngle = 0.0;
        }

        positions.add(newAngle);
        return newAngle;
    }

    public Vector<Double> getAngles() {
        return new Vector<Double>(positions);
    }

    /**
     * Compute the absolute difference between two angles on a circle [0,360[
     * @param first : first angle
     * @param second : second angle
     * @return difference
     */
    private static double getAngleDifference(double first, double second) {
        double firstMod = first % 360.0;
        double secondMod = second % 360.0;

        double diff = (firstMod <= secondMod) ? (secondMod - firstMod) : (360.0 - firstMod + secondMod);

        return diff;
    }

    /**
     * Choose angle farthest from given angle
     * @param potentialAngles : potential valid angles
     * @param angle : reference angle (latest generated angle)
     * @return farthest angle from given angle
     */
    private static double getFarthestAngle(Vector<Double> potentialAngles, double angle) {
        int farthestIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < potentialAngles.size(); ++i) {
            double farthestLength = Math.min(getAngleDifference(angle, potentialAngles.get(farthestIndex)), getAngleDifference(potentialAngles.get(farthestIndex), angle));
            double iLength = Math.min(getAngleDifference(angle, potentialAngles.get(i)), getAngleDifference(potentialAngles.get(i), angle));
            farthestIndex = (iLength > farthestLength) ? i : farthestIndex;
        }

        return potentialAngles.get(farthestIndex);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param longestArcIndexes : indexes of the longest arcs
     * @param arcsLengths : lengths of arcs, in order
     * @param angles : angles, sorted
     * @return angles corresponding to longest arcs
     */
    private static Vector<Double> computePotentialAngles(Vector<Integer> longestArcIndexes, Vector<Double> arcsLengths, Vector<Double> angles) {
        Vector<Double> potentialAngles = new Vector<Double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < longestArcIndexes.size(); ++i) {
            int arcIndex = longestArcIndexes.get(i);
            double arcLength = arcsLengths.get(arcIndex);
            double firstAngle = angles.get(arcIndex);
            double potentialAngle = (firstAngle + (arcLength/2.0)) % 360.0;
            potentialAngles.add(potentialAngle);
        }

        return potentialAngles;
    }

    /**
     * Find index(es) of the longest arc
     * @param arcs : arc lengths, in sorted order
     * @return indexes of the longest arcs
     */
    private static Vector<Integer> getLongestArcIndexes(Vector<Double> arcs) {
        Vector<Integer> arcIndexes = new Vector<Integer>();
        double longestArc = Collections.max(arcs);

        int index = arcs.indexOf(longestArc);
        while(index >= 0) {
            arcIndexes.add(index);
            index = arcs.indexOf(longestArc, index+1);
        }

        return arcIndexes;
    }

    /**
     * Computes and returns a vector of arc lengths from a vector of angles
     * @param vec : vector of angles (sorted)
     * @return vector of arc lengths, in the same order
     */
    private static Vector<Double> computeArcLengths(Vector<Double> vec) {
        Vector<Double> arcs = new Vector<Double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            double firstPos = vec.get(i);
            double secondPos = vec.get((i+1) % vec.size());

            double arcLength = getAngleDifference(firstPos, secondPos);

            arcs.add(arcLength);
        }

        return arcs;
    }
}
```

Usage example.

```
public class UniformAnglesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int TOTAL_ANGLES = 20;

        GenArcs genArcs = new GenArcs();

        // generate
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ANGLES; i++) {
            double newPosArcs = genArcs.generate();

            System.out.println("---------------\ni = " + i);
            System.out.println("arcs   : " + newPosArcs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worthwhile expanding further on Severin's answer, which you found useful.

This question has been extremely well studied for over a century. The solution to this question , typically lies in leveraging the special properties of low discrepancy sequences.

There are many ways to construct low discrepancy sequences. These include the Weyl/Krocker, Van der Corput/Halton, Sobol, and Niederreiter sequences to name a few. In all these cases, they offer methods to distribute n points in d-dimensions in a manner that does not require 'rebalancing' the previously placed points. For example, in 2-dimensions, here are what the first 100 terms for each of the sequences looks like:

[image: "Comparison of various low discrepancy sequences in 2-dimensions]

However, what might not be so clear is that for your question, only the 1-dimensional solution is required. (Note that it is conventionally called 1-dimensional as you are requiring angles that correspond to points that lie on the 1-dimensional perimeter of a circle that is lies in a 2-dimensional place.)

Furthermore, although many of these constructions (eg van der Corput) provide very good results in 1-d, the Weyl/Kronecker solution (as described below) is the only optimal solution to the 1-d problem.

Consider the infinite sequence,

> x[n] = (s + k*n )% 1

for some 'seed' float s,  and some constant 'parameter' float k.

Note that the $(%1)$, which is pronounced 'mod 1' operator takes the fractional part of the argument.

This definition produces an array/list where each of the x[n] lie in the interval [0,1].

The choice of s does not affect the underlying characteristics of the sequence and so for reasons of simplicity is usually set to zero, but is often included by software developers as it offers an option for creatig different sequences simply by setting different seeds.

Critically, it turns out that certain choices of the constant k are better than others in forming a low discrepancy sequence.

**Most importantly, there is one value of k that is provably optimal.**

The optimal case, is when k= phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2 = 1.61803398875..., the golden ratio.

This is why this problem is often called the [golden ratio scheduling problem](http://james.fabpedigree.com/grsched.htm), because the solution uses the ["the golden angle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_angle). Also possibly of interest, is that the construction of the [golden spiral](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/), is also directly related to this sequence.

For further explanations on why this value is optimal, and why k= sqrt(2), is the next best option, see a similar StackExchange post ["Golden ratio mod 1 distribution"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670598/golden-ratio-mod-1-distribution).

Finally, to transform from x[n] to your angles, simply multiply by 360.

Ideally, the angles should be stored as float to allow full representation of all real values between 0 and 360 degrees, and allow an unending list of points.  However, if you really only want integer values as you suggest in your question, then taking the floor(360*x[n]) will still produce excellent results for the n<90, and quite good results for n<360.